# Definition one sided limit of a function

Tags: limits, analysis

Definition(right sided limit): Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ be a limit point of $A \cap (p,\infty)$. Then $\lim_{x\searrow p} f(x)=c$ means that for every sequence $(x_n)_n \subset A$ with $x_n>p$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=p$ there holds $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=c$.

My question: Is there a special reason to demand that $p$ is a limit point of $A \cap (p,\infty)$ or can we also require that $p$ is a limit point of $A \cap [p,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prove that $p$ is a limit point of $X$ if and only if $p$ is a limit point of $X\cup\{p\}.$ Take $X=A\cap (p,\infty)$ and that answers your question.

Comment: this can‘t happen

Comment: I think this would fit better as a comment